# Python - TensorFlow - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named x

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to run a TensorFlow program using python3.6 but I'm facing this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

I found out that I should run the script from another directory, other than the TensorFlow's. However, when I ran the script in the terminal from another directory I get this error:

> line x: from models.object_detection.utils import dataset_util
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'

Moreover, here is my directory looks like:

```
    - root
        - models
        .    - object_detection
        .    .    - utils
        .         .   + dataset_util.py
        - my_folder
        .    + my_file.py
```

How can I solve the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: You are running python from tensorflow source directory. Please change the directory to another folder. eg. cd ~/ might help

Comment: @Mitiku I know it. As I mentioned in the second part of my question, when I change my directory, I face a new error telling me: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'

Comment: The module models is found in "Tensorflow Object Detection API", Did you install "Tensorflow Object Detection API"?> If you don't please follow https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md and install it.

Comment: @Mitiku I have installed it correctly, but I was wondering where should I put the module models? In the tensorflow under the site-packages of python?

Answer (score 0):

I received this error when I was running tensorflow-gpu instead of tensorflow on windows with a machine that didn't have a graphics card.